# Need to update GTK+ on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, gtk

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04. When i tried to build a project from source i got following  message

```
configure: error: Package requirements (gtk+-3.0 >= 3.6) were not met:
Requested 'gtk+-3.0 >= 3.6' but version of GTK+ is 3.4.2
```

I guess i have to update the GTK+. can some one tell me how

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One suggestion I got from the development mailing list is to use newer version of Ubuntu (13.04). This might not be a perfect solution, but it worked.